# How to select all Products for each Category in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, select, group-by

I have to tables Products and Categories (Like in Northwind DB).

Categories (CatId, CatName):

```
Id   Name
1    Electronics
2    Foods
3    Fruits
```

Products (ProId, CatId, ProName):

```
ProId    CatId    ProName
1        1        Television
2        1        Computer
3        2        Beer
4        3        Lemon
5        3        Blackberry
6        3        Apple
```

Now i wanna select all Products for each Categories, i want result like this:

```
Electronics
ProId    CatId    ProName
    1        1        Television
    2        1        Computer

Foods
ProId    CatId    ProName
    3        2        Beer

Fruits
ProId    CatId    ProName
    4        3        Lemon
    5        3        Blackberry
    6        3        Apple
```

I think i will using Group-by. But i don't know how.

Comment: What have you tried to do?  It helps with the answer if you can show some of the things that you have tried.

Comment: I just have idea and i have not tried to do yet. In actuality, i have tried using Group By and Order by but i have not received good result. I want for each Category return for me as one table (one datatable in dataset).

Comment: You would do this by joining your tables together. It is the very basis of retrieving data from any relational database. https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: @Sean Lange: No, you can see my purpose in my previous comment.

Comment: Here is the problem. It is not clear what you expect here. If you want a separate table for each category you will have to run a select statement for each category. A single select statement cannot return multiple results. Help us understand what you want more clearly and we can help you find a solution.

Comment: Actually, before you do anything else, you should go through either some basic SQL tutorials on the internet, or a beginning SQL book.   Then at least you should try to do what you want to do, and if it doesn't work, come back and post your code, and what is going wrong with it.

Comment: @Sean Lange: Exactly, i want a separate table for each category. If i do it in C# by using for each Categories and select all products is easy. But  I want to find a simple solution to resolve my problem within the SQL instead C-sharp.

Comment: You don't create separate tables.   Show some effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options.  Run the first on first.  You will see that it returns 3 data sets.

The second will create actual tables on your server.

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max);Select @SQL = coalesce(@sql,';')+'Select * from Products where CatID='+cast(ID as varchar(25))+';' from Categories;Exec(@SQL);
```

OR

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max);Select @SQL = coalesce(@sql,';')+'Select * into [dbo].['+name+'] from Products where CatID='+cast(ID as varchar(25))+';' from Categories;Exec(@SQL);
```

Comment: This solution cannot resolve my problem. I want a separate table for each category in single select statement. I want to find a simple solution within the SQL instead c-sharp.

Comment: Would you mind a stored procedure to produce x number of tables?

Comment: As Sean Lange mentioned, you can not create multiple tables in one select.  You can however have multiple tables from a stored procedure.  Just let me know if you need some assistance

Comment: Sorry. My English is not good. In my previous comment, i said "i want to use single select statement" but in actually that could be a store procedure. I have tried using GROUP BY and XML PATH and return CatId, CatName, ProductName for each category on one row. Can you help me to create a procedure to return a separate table for each category.

Comment: Sure, give me a minute

Comment: OK, Just one last question, are you creating actual tables on your server, or are use consuming these tables in another app?

Comment: When is run two query, SQL Server has error: Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 2
'concat' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you on

Comment: Try Select @@version

Comment: My SQL Server version is: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64)   Apr  2 2010 15:48:46   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: )

Comment: Updated answer for 2008

Comment: I have understood your idea when i print @SQL and then i have customize your query to solve my problem. Thanks!